# Why Flow meters are some times showing -ve fluctuating Values in Pressurized Pipe lines

Tags: classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, water

In our Underground Water reservior we are pumping water by Hydro-pneumatic pumps to maintain same pressure till last connection.

in order to measure the flow we have installed precise electromagnetic flowmeters to make water balance .
Now the problem is that some times in a day my flow meters are showing Peaks in Negative flow also which i am unable to understand that if this is a meter fault or there is some concept which i need to understand .

Comment: This would probably be better asked on [the Engineering Stack Exchange](http://engineering.stackexchange.com/). While we're pretty good on fundamental physics I doubt we have many experts on hydraulic engineering.